# How do I sync my local website directory with /home/public at the remote host?

Tags: sync

I have been using [`Transmit.app`](http://www.panic.com/transmit/) to sync my local website directory to `/home/public` at my remote webhost.

However I am fed up doing this graphically, clicking 10-15 times, everytime I make a small change to my website.

How can I do this from the command line? I have ssh access to my remote webhost. I have never used `rsync` some pointers might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
rsync -avh --delete /local/directory username@remotehost:/home/public
```

This will create `directory` within `/home/public`. If you however want to have the contents of `directory` directly in `/home/public` use something like (note that trailing slash):

```
rsync -avh --delete /local/directory/ username@remotehost:/home/public
```

Check out `man rsync` for more options. The ones used above:

- `--delete` will remove nonexisting files on the remote host, so be careful about what you transfer.
- `a` is for "archiving" and should be useful in most cases
- `h` will enable human readable file sizes

Some additional options you may want to use:

- `--progress` to see the current progress as well
- `--dry-run` to see what would theoretically be transmitted (but don't actually transmit anything)

Answer (score 1):

```
rsync -avhe ssh --delete /home/user/dir/ user@remote.host.com:dir/
```

Quite simple and straightforward.

Hopefully you use git in your development process, then you can just use it instead.

More info on rsync here:

http://www.linux.com/news/enterprise/storage/8200-back-up-like-an-expert-with-rsync

To deploy with git:

http://philsturgeon.co.uk/news/2010/02/Deploying-websites-with-Git